Functional Test execution fails with FailedtoStartError
I am trying to run the bitcoin testframework, a specific test to illustrate this case is feature_rbf.py
Env: Ubuntu -windows 
Bitcoin version: 27.x - built from source.

When I run the daemon independently, it all works fine, however when the testframework tries to start it fails. In the task manager I do see a daemon appear but it’s relatively short-lived.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated please?
The error I am getting is shown below
2024-09-03T11:12:21.831000Z TestFramework (INFO): PRNG seed is: 7814762433087298742
2024-09-03T11:12:21.832000Z TestFramework (INFO): Initializing test directory /tmp/bitcoin_func_test_xamnzyvx

2024-09-03T11:12:41.635000Z TestFramework (ERROR): Unexpected exception caught during testing
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 130, in main
    self.setup()
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 296, in setup
    self.setup_chain()
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 387, in setup_chain
    self._initialize_chain()
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 827, in _initialize_chain
    self.start_node(CACHE_NODE_ID)
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 541, in start_node
    node.wait_for_rpc_connection()
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_node.py", line 257, in wait_for_rpc_connection
    raise FailedToStartError(self._node_msg(
test_framework.test_node.FailedToStartError: [node 0] bitcoind exited with status 3 during initialization. Assertion failed: base.is_absolute(), file util/fs.cpp, line 38
************************

2024-09-03T11:12:41.686000Z TestFramework (INFO): Stopping nodes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/feature_rbf.py", line 731, in <module>
    ReplaceByFeeTest().main()
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 154, in main
    exit_code = self.shutdown()
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 313, in shutdown
    self.stop_nodes()
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_framework.py", line 574, in stop_nodes
    node.stop_node(wait=wait, wait_until_stopped=False)
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_node.py", line 377, in stop_node
    self.stop(wait=wait)
  File "/usr/src/bitcoin/test/functional/test_framework/test_node.py", line 207, in __getattr__
    assert self.rpc_connected and self.rpc is not None, self._node_msg("Error: no RPC connection")
AssertionError: [node 0] Error: no RPC connection
[node 0] Cleaning up leftover process


After some poking around it looks like its failing because of this
Value Error No RPC credentials
I tried elbowing in some RPC username/pwd combos . but that didn't work either
this is now the bitcoind start cmd
['/usr/src/bitcoin/src/bitcoind.exe', '-datadir=/usr/src/bitcoin/test/cache/node0', '-logtimemicros', '-debug', '-debugexclude=libevent', '-debugexclude=leveldb', '-debugexclude=rand', '-uacomment=testnode0', '-disablewallet', '-logthreadnames', '-logsourcelocations', '-loglevel=trace', '-v2transport=0']
